# How can a view in DrupalGap, which is used by a custom module, NOT be cached but instead be called each and every time?

Tags: 7, views, caching, javascript

I am using a [Local Task Menu](http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Menus/Local_Tasks) as demonstrated in the docs to present one more tab named `members` next to `View` and `Edit`. This tab is showed only to group nodes and i have connected a custom view inside Drupal which fetches the members of this group. Works good. Fetches, displays and links the members in the appropriate page.
But the problem is that this view is called only the first time. In other words, if a user subscribes or unsubscribes from this group after the first call, then this change won't be updated and showed.
In Views `Caching:None` and `Block caching:Do not cache` but i think this is a matter of drupalgap menu cache.
Is there a way i can make this specific view not to be cached but instead be called every time the menu tab is clicked?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

DrupalGap 7 is a multi-page application, which means as you navigate around, pages that you previously visited remain in the DOM. Then when you navigate back to that page, it is already in the DOM, so it isn't rebuilt.

All you need to do is add the `reloadPage` option to your link and that'll force the page to be reloaded upon navigation: http://docs.drupalgap.org/7/Pages/Reloading_Pages

```
/**
 * Implements hook_menu().
 */
function my_module_menu() {
  var items = {};
  items['foo'] = {
    title: 'Foo',
    path: 'foo-bar',
    options: {
      reloadPage: true
    }
  };
  return items;
}
```